# PHP regex issues when trying to match

Tags: php, regex

I'm running into issues when trying to use the preg_match function in php, I've been trying to check the first character of the string that is provided form a form the user inputs, this is retrieved via the code below, I've checked numerous times with echo to see what is being fetched and it doesn't seem to be a problem from the retrieval side and more the preg_match. I've been using the code below to check for the first character to make sure it's a letter or apostrophe and every-time the pattern contains the '^' character it makes the whole match fail, I've also tested this on a separate code with other matches and the same outcomes end with a fail even though it should work.

```
//Code for retrieving name from input.
$name = $_POST['name'];

//Preg_match with conditional statement.
//testing that starting character either letter or apostrophe.
        //Condition 3, starts correctly
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]|[\']).*/i", '$name')) {
        echo "Name Accepted. <br>";
        $validName = true;
    }else{
        $validName = false;
        echo "$name";
        echo "Name must start with letter or Apostrophe. <br>";
    }
```

Here's an example of the other tests to check:

```
$string = "9anny--";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]/", '$string')) {
    echo "Name Accepted. <br>";
}else{
    echo "$string<br>";
    echo "Name must start with number. <br>";
}
```

Followed by the output from it:

output:

9anny--  //Echo testing the input went through okay.

Name must start with number.  //Failed.

Now I'm worrying that I won't be able to check the first character without using ^ but there shouldn't be an issue anyway so I'm wondering what the problem is with my regex statements.

Any help or feedback would be amazing and sorry if this problem is something trivial, I'm pretty new to working with php and regex statements. I have tried using resources online but still if they contain the ^ then it means the condition will fail every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, this is one of those "well duh" moments.

`'$name'` is quite literally the text `$name`, not the contents of the `$name` variable. Single-quoted strings do not interpolate variables like double-quoted strings do.

Just remove the quotes entirely if you want to use the variable's value!